# How to branch res.send based on different req.body's key on same page?

Tags: node.js, express

So, I am creating an API wherein depending on the request that is sent to the NodeJS Server, the response that is sent is different.

There are 2 JSON requests that happen:

- One of them includes a key called `status`
- whereas the other one has a key called `customer_code`

How can I change the res.send based on the req.body?

I did this but it fails:

```js
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var toCheckStatus = req.body.notify.status
    var toCheckID = req.body.validate.customer_code
    let toCheckIDKey;
    if (toCheckStatus){ 
        res.send({"notifyResult": {"result": "ok"}})
    }else{
        fs.readFile('./codes.json', function(err, data){
            if (err) throw err
            var cleanData = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i=0;i < Object.keys(cleanData).length; i++){
            if(cleanData[i].customer_code == toCheckID){
                toCheckIDKey = i;
            }}
            if (toCheckIDKey > -1){
                res.send ({
                    "validateResponse": {
                    "decision": "pass"
                    }
                    });
            }else res.send({
                "validateResponse": {
                "decision": "reject"
                }
                })
        })   
    }
});
```

The errors I get is one of the flowing:

> Cannot read property 'customer_code' of undefined

> Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things may cause the error you mentioned:

1. You may need to add [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware to parse json request body.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

2. check that `validate` property does exist in your request

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks mate